# Global name 'img' is not defined?

Tags: python, opencv, interface, wxpython

I'm new programming interfaces. I'm creating a simple interface with wxpython and openCV to open an image, save it and close the interface. You can see my code below. I can open an image and close the interface. Even, I show dialog boxes for the opening and saving routines but saving is where I have problems. I don't know how to send to OnSave the img (image object) to be saved. This is not clear to me. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

```
import wx
import cv2

class MyMenu(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(200, 150))
    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    file = wx.Menu()
    edit = wx.Menu()
    help = wx.Menu()
    file.Append(101, '&Open', 'Open a new document')
    file.Append(102, '&Save', 'Save the document')
    file.AppendSeparator()
    quit = wx.MenuItem(file, 105, '&Quit\tCtrl+Q', 'Quit the Application')
    file.AppendItem(quit)

    menubar.Append(file, '&File')
    menubar.Append(edit, '&Edit')
    menubar.Append(help, '&Help')

    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
    self.CreateStatusBar()

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, id=101)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, id=102)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=105)

def OnOpen(self, event):
    openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "",
                                   "PNG files (*.png)|*.png|BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp",
                                   wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
    openFileDialog.ShowModal()
    path = openFileDialog.GetPath()
    openFileDialog.Destroy()
    img = cv2.imread(str(path))
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    return img

def OnSave(self, event):
    saveFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save As", "", "",
                                   "PNG files (*.png)|*.png|BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp",
                                   wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
    saveFileDialog.ShowModal()
    path_save = saveFileDialog.GetPath()
    print path_save
    saveFileDialog.Destroy()
    cv2.imwrite(str(path_save), img)

def OnQuit(self, event):
    self.Close()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
       frame = MyMenu(None, -1, 'menu1.py')
       frame.Show(True)
       return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

I get the following error:

NameError: global name 'img' is not defined

EDIT (final version):

```
import wx
import cv2
import numpy as np


class MyMenu(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(200, 150))
    img = np.array([0])
    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    file = wx.Menu()
    edit = wx.Menu()
    help = wx.Menu()
    file.Append(101, '&Open', 'Open a new document')
    file.Append(102, '&Save', 'Save the document')
    file.AppendSeparator()
    quit = wx.MenuItem(file, 105, '&Quit\tCtrl+Q', 'Quit the Application')
    file.AppendItem(quit)

    menubar.Append(file, '&File')
    menubar.Append(edit, '&Edit')
    menubar.Append(help, '&Help')

    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
    self.CreateStatusBar()

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, id=101)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, id=102)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=105)

def OnOpen(self, event):
    openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "",
                                   "PNG files (*.png)|*.png|BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp",
                                   wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
    openFileDialog.ShowModal()
    path = openFileDialog.GetPath()
    openFileDialog.Destroy()
    self.img = cv2.imread(str(path))
    cv2.imshow('img', self.img)

def OnSave(self, event):
    saveFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Save As", "", "",
                                   "PNG files (*.png)|*.png|BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp",
                                   wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT)
    saveFileDialog.ShowModal()
    path_save = saveFileDialog.GetPath()
    print path_save
    saveFileDialog.Destroy()
    cv2.imwrite(str(path_save), self.img)

def OnQuit(self, event):
    self.Close()


class MyApp(wx.App):
def OnInit(self):
    frame = MyMenu(None, -1, 'menu1.py')
    frame.Show(True)
    return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Sorry, it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 47, in OnSave
    cv2.imwrite(str(path_save), img)
NameError: global name 'img' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at it you mean the `img` used in `OnSave`, if you look, `img` isn't defined in the scope, nor is it *globally* defined.

Comment: Ok, where I have to define it globally? I tried something like this `img = numpy.array([0],[0])` before of my class MyMenu, then I opened an image and when I tried to save it there was no error this time, but the saved image was empty. I want to open an image, modify it and then save it.

Comment: That's because wxWidgets expects a wxImage I would imagine. You need to read the documentation.